# Integration constant vector

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, indefinite-integrals, constants

When integrating a vector expression, why is the constant of integration a vector?

Is there a certain proof that shows this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $R^{2}$:

If **r**$(t) = f(t)$**i** + g(t)**j**

$\int$ **r**$(t)dt$ = $[\int f(t)dt ]$**i** + $[\int g(t)dt ]$**j**

Let $F'(t)=f(t)$ and $G'(t)=g(t)$, then

$\int$ **r**$(t)dt$ = $[F(t) + C_{1} ]$**i** + $[G(t) + C_{2}  ]$**j**

$\int$ **r**$(t)dt$ = $[F(t)$**i** + $G(t)$**j**$]$ + $[C_{1}$**i** + $C_{1}$**j**$] = $ **R**$(t) + $**C**

where **R'**$(t) = r(t)$

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\int\begin{bmatrix}f_1(x)\\ \vdots\\ f_n(x)\end{bmatrix}dx\underbrace{=}_{\text{def}}\begin{bmatrix}\int f_1(x)dx\\ \vdots\\\int f_n(x)dx\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}F_1(x)+C_1\\ \vdots\\ F_n(x)+C_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}F_1(x)\\ \vdots\\ F_n(x)\end{bmatrix}+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}C_1\\ \vdots\\C_n\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{C}},$$ where $F_1,\ldots,F_n$ are primitives of $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ respectively.